# Remove json field in ASP MVC WebApi Action Method

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have a controller that accepts a model UpdateProductCommand like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult UpdateProduct(UpdateProductCommand command)
{
    command.AuditUserName = this.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
    // ....
}
```

For security issues, the `AuditUserName` field should never be set outside (from the API call).

How can I remove (or truncate) the value of this field from JSON request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by a following `ModelBinder`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class FieldRemoverModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string content = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
        JToken property = json.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        property?.Parent.Remove();
        bindingContext.Model = json.ToObject(bindingContext.ModelType);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult UpdateProduct(([ModelBinder(typeof(FieldRemoverModelBinder), Name = nameof(UpdateProductCommand.AuditUserName))]UpdateProductCommand command)
{
    // here command.AuditUserName will always be empty, no matter what's in json
```

Comment: That is not removing it from the request (its just not binding it). And since your code in the method is setting it anyway, what is the point?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I don't send this field in json all all, but API will be exposed in the Internet. So someone might want to play and make break it with raw queries.

Comment: That is why we use view models containing only those properties that we want to be bound from the request :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yeah it was my first approach, by was rejected by our tech lead due to some other design requirements (long story, big system).

Comment: For `Newtonsoft.Json` is there some attribute that we can use on model/object? (to remove some property/field)

Comment: found this attribute to put on the property to ignore `[JsonIgnore]`

Answer (score 0):

That's what DTOs are for.

You can just create another class (`UpdateProductCommandDto` for example) that has only the properties you need / want to be used as the input, and then you can just use something like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to map it to a new instance of `UpdateProductCommand`.